# CCSprite Color Blend Similar to kCGBlendModeColor on UIImage

Tags: colors, overlay, uicolor, ccsprite, blending

I am trying to overlay color on a sprite image and have questions about how to blend the color with the sprite. I've used the following `updateImageTint` routine to overlay color on a `UIImage` and the output is what I am hoping for. The image maintains whites but shades of gray are saturated or burned with the specified overlay color. The param `kCGBlendModeColor` seems to do the trick for standard `UIImage` color blending.

However, I am trying to get the same effect using a sprite, but the color looks simply like it's coloring on top of the entire image, white areas and all. I'm assuming this is a blend issue. Is there a set of parameters I can pass to the setBlendFunc to get the output to match the `updateImageTint` method below?

I've tried this...but with no luck

```
[spriteToAdjust setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_ONE, GL_ONE }];
[spriteToAdjust setColor:ccc3(red*255.0,green*255.0,blue*255.0)];

-(UIImage*) updateImageTint:(UIImage*) img toColor:(UIColor*) toColor
{

// begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

// get a reference to that context we created
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// set the fill color
UIColor *color = toColor;
[color setFill];

// translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// set the blend mode to color burn, and the original image
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColor);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

// set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (color burn) a colored rectangle
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, img.CGImage);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

// generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//return the color-burned image
return coloredImg;
}
```